# Случайная выборка из базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql, запрос, случайные-числа

Наслышан из сети, якобы функция RAND() случайного выбора из базы работает каряво, иными словами жрет много ресурсов. При нескольких тысячах посетителей, сервер не выдержит и ляжет. Хорошо, нашел альтернативный способ в сети: Брать последний id, а после генерить случайное и число и вытаскивать. Но у меня ситуация иная:

> Нужно вытащить 5 случайных записей из базы, где в базе есть пустые id. Пример: (1 4 9 14 20 21 22 25... и т.д.)

Как можно решить данную задачу. Заранее благодарен.

**Функция составленная из ответов к теме:**

```
public function random_query($table = 'users', $select = '*')
{
    $count = $this -> db -> count_all('users');
    $pos = array(
        rand(1, $count),
        rand(1, $count),
        rand(1, $count),
    );

    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET '.$pos[0]. ' INTO @id1;'.
        'SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET '.$pos[1]. ' INTO @id2;'.
        'SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET '.$pos[2]. ' INTO @id3;'.
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2, @id3);';

    $res = $this -> db -> query($sql);

    return $res;
}
```

Использую библиотеку Code-igniter, поэтому запросы выполняются немного по-другому.
Попробовал сделать так, как есть уже из ответов к теме. Вылезли ругательства на запрос. Я подумал, что возможно фреймворк не приемлет несколько Select в одном запросе, я их разделил. Немного дополнил функцию и упростил. Все заработало, но все же, почему то, при выводе случайных данных, может вывестись только 0,1,2,3 из 3 записей, в зависимости от того, нашел ли он запись или нет. Я думаю, что возможно это из-за моего разделения запросов.
Поправьте мою функцию, из-за чего может быть такая ситуация.

Comment: Выбираем идентификаторы всех записей, вытягиваем нужно количество рандомных идентификаторов, делаем запрос вида `WHERE primary_key IN (randValues.join(", "))` Если нужен код - уточните, если и этот вариант тяжелый для сервера, тогда делайте что-то типа варианта предложенного @ReinRaus 'ом

Comment: @Nick, обрати внимание на то, что у меня все запросы склеены в одну строку. По сути, это один запрос из нескольких SELECT-ов. А ошибки у тебя возникают потому, что ты пытаешься получить результат от запросов с `INTO`.

Еще, у тебя считается не количество, а максимальный ID. Кол-во нужно считать запросом с `COUNT()`. Это важно потому, что дальше будут генериться случайные позиции в списке, а из них, уже, идентификаторы записей.

Comment: Вот оно что. Спасибо. Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: @KiTe, Исправил. Ругается на синтаксис запроса. Функцию написал в вопросе. Использовал то, что было написано.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не могли бы вы написать свою версию кода. Пытался воссоздать из того, что написали но не вышло.

Comment: @Nick, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `RAND()` предельно проста и работает в MySQL корректно и быстро.

Проблемы производительности-же возникают не из-за `RAND()`, а при сортировке не по индексу (по очевидным причинам, сортировка по индексу для данной задачи невозможна), т.е. из-за т.н. `filesort`.

Вольный перевод из [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> - Using filesort
>
> Что-бы узнать в каком порядке извлекать строки, MySQL должен выполнить дополнительную сортировку. Для этого потребуется просмотр **всех строк** в соответствии с типом связывания таблиц и сохранение ключей с указателями на строку, согласно выражению WHERE.

[Алгоритм работы `filesort`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html):

> Оригинальный алгоритм `filesort` работает следующим образом:
>
> 1. Читаются все строки согласно заданному ключу или путем полного сканирования таблицы. Строки не соответствующие выражению `WHERE` пропускаются.
> 2. Для каждой строки в буфер сохраняются пары значений: ключ для сортировки (прим.: тот что указан в ORDER BY) и указатель на строку. Размер буфера задается системной переменной `sort_buffer_size`.
> 3. Когда буфер полностью заполнен, данные сортируются алгоритмом quicksort, а результат сохраняется во временный файл. Затем сохраняется указатель на отсортированный блок. (Если все данные поместились в буфер, то временный файл не создается)
> 4. Предыдущие шаги повторяются, пока не будут прочитаны все строки.
> 5. Запускается алгоритм слияния (`MERGEBUFF`) блоков в другой временный файл. Это действие повторяется, пока все блоки не окажутся во втором временном файле.
> 6. Предыдущий пункт повторяется пока не останется хотя-бы `MERGEBUFF2` блоков.
> 7. При последнем слиянии в результирующий файл записываются только указатели на строки (второе значение пары).
> 8. Далее строки читаются в соответствующем порядке по указателям из результирующего фала. Для оптимизации этого шага, сначала читается большой блок указателей, сортируется и
>    затем считываются строки в отсортированном порядке в буфер строк. Размер буфера задается системной переменной `read_rnd_buffer_size`

Не трудно догадаться, что на большом количестве строк такой алгоритм будет работать очень медленно. А значит и медленно будут работать запросы вида `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND();` (вместо `RAND()` тут может быть любое другое вычисляемое выражение).

Что в таком случае делать? Если первичный ключ является целочисленным с последовательной нумерацией (грубо говоря auto_increment поле), то самый очевидный выход - это отказаться от сортировки по выражению и вместо этого заранее рассчитывать случайное число от `MIN(id)` до `MAX(id)`, а затем делать выбрать строку с `ID` наиболее близким к этому числу:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table AS t 
JOIN (SELECT ((SELECT MIN(id) - 1 FROM table) + RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) - MIN(id) 
               FROM table)) AS id) AS rand
WHERE t.id >= rand.id
ORDER BY t.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Подробнее про данный алгоритм можно прочитать здесь: [оригинал](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/), [перевод](http://hudson.su/2010/09/16/mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand/).

Основные недостатки такого подхода:

- Для выборки нескольких случайных строк нужно делать несколько запросов. Однако это все равно будет намного быстрее, чем `filesort`.
- Если будут большие "дырки" среди `id`, то выборка будет менее случайной. Хотя частично эта проблема решается по ссылке выше.

PS Что бы в выборку не попадали предыдущие строки, достаточно добавить запрос условие `t.id NOT IN (...)`

Comment: Тяжелая обработка с rand() - это обработка всех данных. Хмм... выдергивая одним запросом ту часть записей, в которой необходимо произвести случайную выборку, а после выдергивать рандом из выбранных записей... - про это вы имели введу. В таком случае rand() можно использовать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Прочитал статьи, которые вы указали. Довольно интересные. Как работать разобрался. Единственное, что прочитав не понял. В статье говорится, что нужно выравнивать последовательность id, чтобы числа шли по порядку. Обязательно ли это делать? Без выравнивания будет работать?

Comment: Первый вопрос не совсем понял. При наличии `RAND()` в `ORDER BY` всегда **будет использоваться `filesort` по всей выборке**. И даже если вы напишете `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` все равно будут сканироваться все строки попадающие под условие `WHERE`.

> В статье говорится, что нужно выравнивать последовательность id, чтобы числа шли по порядку. Обязательно ли это делать? Без выравнивания будет работать?

Не обязательно. Работать будет.

Answer (score 7):

Можно попробовать отталкиваться не от идентификатора, а от позиции записи в общем перечне.

Определяем общее кол-во:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

Через PHP генерим пять случайных позиций в этом кол-ве:

```
$pos = array(
    rand(0, $count),
    rand(0, $count),
    rand(0, $count),
    rand(0, $count),
    rand(0, $count),
);
```

И выполняем запрос:

```
$sql =
    // Здесь определяются ID соответствующие случайным позициям
    'SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[0] . ' INTO @id1;' .
    'SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[1] . ' INTO @id2;' .
    'SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[2] . ' INTO @id3;' .
    'SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[3] . ' INTO @id4;' .
    'SELECT id FROM table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[4] . ' INTO @id5;' .
    // А здесь уже сама выборка записей по определенными ID
    'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2, @id3, @id4, @id5);';
```

**UPD:** Функция на PHP которая строит SQL-запрос выглядела бы примерно так:

```
function getRandRowsSQL($table_name, $key_name, $real_count, $count)
{
    // Проверяем кол-во на максимум
    if( $count > $real_count ) $count = $real_count;
    $sql = '';
    if( $count > 0 ){
        // Создаем массив уникальных позиций
        $pos = array();
        $pos[0] = rand(1, $real_count);
        $i = 1;
        while( $i < $count ){
            $pos[$i] = rand(1, $real_count);
            for( $j = 0; $j < $i; $j++ ){
                $is_unique = ($pos[$j] != $pos[$i]);
                if( !$is_unique ) break;
            }
            if( $is_unique ) $i++;
        }
        // Строим SQL
        for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
            $sql .=
                'SELECT ' . $key_name . ' FROM ' . $table_name .
                ' LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $pos[$i] . ' INTO @id' . $i . ";\n";
        }
        $sql .= 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ' . $key_name . ' IN (@id0';
        for( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++ ){
            $sql .= ', @id' . $i;
        }
        $sql .= ');';
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

- `$table_name` - имя таблицы
- `$key_name` - название поля primary_key
- `$real_count` - общее кол-во записей в таблице (получаем через `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`)
- `$count` - кол-во случайных записей которые нужно выбирать запросом
- `return` - на выходе функции текст SQL запроса

Для примера что получится можно сделать:

```
<pre><?= getRandRowsSQL('table', 'id', 1000, 5) ?></pre>
```

Comment: 6 запросов...

Comment: До клиента доходит результат только последнего. Запросы с `INTO` свой результат возвращают в mysql-переменные на стороне сервера. И все они выполняются очень быстро.

И дело не в количестве. Один запрос с `ORDER BY RAND()` может положить сервак на лопатки, в то время как на эти 6-ть уйдет до 30мсек.

Comment: Только что сравнил. В таблице 250000 записей.
ORDER BY RAND() отработал за 968 мсек, а мои 6 запросов за 35 мсек.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5` ?

Comment: А кто писал что ORDER BY RAND() лучшее решение? О_о

Comment: отличный вариант.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да хоть `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.
По времени выполнения результат не изменится. Если бы в этом случае от `LIMIT` что-то зависело, то никто бы не напрягался. `LIMIT` ограничивает выдачу, но уже после того как отработает `ORDER BY`. А, так как в случае с `RAND()` индексами не воспользуешься серверу придется выстроить всю таблицу. Это и есть суть проблемы, по которой топикстартер задал вопрос.

Comment: Отличный вариант по сравнению с rand(), сейчас буду испытывать. Единственное, что я бы изменил, это не считать количество всех записей с помощью COUNT(), а вытаскивать последний id таблицы. После, из всех выше написанных кодов сделать одну гибкую функцию. А так спасибо.

Comment: @KiTE в вашем варианте существует вероятность, выборки одинаковых строк. исправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: @FLK, да верояность есть, правда на больших списках она стремится к 0. Чтобы эту самую вероятность устранить нужно немного поколдовать с PHP-кодом `$pos = array(...)`. Но, это вы уж как-нибудь самостоятельно, если решитесь воспользоваться предложенным приемом.

Comment: @KiTE я не про себя, просто этот ответ будут видеть любители копипаста и далеко не у всех будет несколько тысяч строк в базе. предлагаю написать что нить типа $pos - массив уникальных, рандомных значений в диапазоне от 1 до count(*), а реализацию оставить на усмотрение читателей.

Comment: `OFFSET` достаточно дорогая операция. При `OFFSET` = `COUNT(*)` mysql придется пройтись по всей базе (в вашем случае по всему индексу).

По сути ваш алгоритм по производительности эквивалентен:

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)

Comment: Т.е., как я понимаю, вариант предложенный мною один из оптимальных?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, в принципе да. Единственное, в случае очень большего числа строк (e.g. 1 000 000 строк), могут начать тормозить PHP'шные массивы. Ну и памяти и понадобится не мало.

Answer (score 5):

Если эти id важные, то можно создать ещё один столбец с `auto_increment` и `primary_key`. И каждый раз перед основными запросами, удалять его, создавать снова и делать по нему выборку. :-) Шучу, конечно, но больше не представляю как сделать, если только не брать наугад большие диапазоны (в надежде захватить минимум 5 записей), перемешивать их и выводить только 5 случайных записей. :-)

Меня не слушать, я блондинка. :-) Ну точно же, если у id уже `primary_key`, то не получится. :-(

Comment: Интересная логика. При таком раскладе функция rand() будет оптимальным вариантом. =) У меня была мысль сделать выборку в цикле методом тира, если попал в ид, то вывести, если нет, то продим по базе, но как это написать. =)

Comment: Выборка в цикле - самоубийство. Можно весь день "стрелять" и ни разу не попасть. :-)

А если выбирать все id их помещать в массив и брать элементы со случайными ключами, где в значении будут id? Затем формировать строку из 5 чисел и использовать её в запросе. Просто делать запрос типа ... WHERE id IN(4,14,22,9,25). :-) Можно не все id, а с лимитом и даже всегда в случайных местах. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
function query( $query ) {
  return  mysql_query( $query );
}

function fetchAll( $queryResult ) {
  $data = array();
  if( $queryResult ) {
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult) ) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $data;
}

/**
* @param {String} $howMuch      Количество случайных записей
* @param {String} $tableName    Имя таблицы
* @param {Int}    $primaryKey   Первичный ключ
* @example
*  $randArticles = getRandomRows( 10, 'articles', 'article_id' );
*/
function getRandomRows( $howMuch, $tableName, $primaryKey = 'id' ) {
  $result = array();
  $getIdsQuery = 'SELECT ' . $primaryKey . ' FROM ' . $tableName;
  $ids = fetchAll( query( $getIdsQuery ) );
  if( $ids ) {
    $idsTotal = count($ids);
    $howMuch = $howMuch <= $idsTotal ? $howMuch : $idsTotal;
    $randomUniqueIndexes = array_rand( $ids, $howMuch );
    $randIdsArray = array();
    for( $i=0; $i<$howMuch; ++$i ) {
      $randIdsArray[] = $ids[ $randomUniqueIndexes[ $i ] ][ $primaryKey ];
    }
    $finalQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName . ' WHERE ' . $primaryKey . ' IN ('. implode(', ', $randIdsArray) .')';
    $result = fetchAll(query($finalQuery));
  }
  return $result;
}
```

---

upd: функция переписана и проверена.

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно теперь только  преобразовать под фреймворк code-igniter, но разобраться в коде не очень получается. =)

Comment: Да ладно вам, что, в коде, непонятного?..

Comment: Как стало ясно, ваш способ довольно оптимальный. В чужом коде - как в чужой стране. Я работаю с code-igniter, там все запросы работают с помощью библиотек. Классы. Да и в принципе, в стиле письма кода тяжко разобраться, в моем случае. :D

Answer (score 2):

Оптимизируйте базу к примеру раз в день при перезагрузке сервера- удаляйте пробелы между ID выстраивая их в последовательный ряд. При выборке пользуйтесь найденным Вами альтернативным алгоритмом, но при этом крайнее значение должно быть ограничено последним ID на момент оптимизации.
Да. Вы не сможете выбрать в этом случае записи сделанные за сегодня (между последней оптимизацией и настоящим моментом), но насколько это принципиально при большом количестве записей?
P.S. Если изменять ID невозможно ввиду сложных взаимосвязей в БД- создайте еще одно поле, и  оптимизируйте только его, выстраивая по порядку раз в день.

Comment: Перестраивать первичные ключи не самый лучший вариант.

Comment: Согласен, но добавить поле и работать с ним (что, собственно написано автором ответа), не смотря на то что это костыль - нормально. Единственное что я вообще не вижу ситуаций когда можно было бы безопасно хранить изменять primary_key таблицы. Как минимум появляется риск потери данных и т.д (это не говоря о варианте со сложной структурой БД)

Comment: Теоретически можно, если стоят внешние связи с параметром каскадного обновления. Но это моветон. Как один из примеров, юзер сохранил у себя в избранном статью `http://site.com/news/188/`. Заходит по этой ссылке через некоторое время и видит совершенно другую статью.

Comment: И это в т.ч. я и подразумевал когда писал риск потери данных

Answer (score 0):

только что придумал вариант =)
взять функцию даты и выбрать ийдишники по ней

Comment: Зачем Вам два ответа?

Comment: он сделал это не специально, это **баг ХэшКод'а** (чаще проявляет себя во время добавления вопроса)